# assembler code of a fragment of C++ code

Tags: c++, disassembly

Result of compilation of C/C++ code is assembler code. In what assembler code next line will be compiled:

```
a[0] = 1
```

where  `a` is an integer array in some C++ program.

Comment: I really don't understand why it is not a real question. You just don't know the answer.

Comment: Why not simply compile your code, save the assembly and have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use GCC for a compiler, you can use `--save-temps` which prevents the intermediate files (including the assembly output) from being deleted after it's done.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html